# What is a word to describe something that belongs exclusively to or is used only by one person or a group of people?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-usage, idioms, vocabulary, lexicon

I'm trying to find a word (or idiom or phrase) that describes something which is perceived as belonging to one person or group of people only. To contextualise this question I'll provide the paragraph in which I need to insert this word:

> But while the community of administrative assistants the world over can thank the cast and creators behind The Devil Wears Prada for flagging their struggle to the public, they should also be disgruntling at the fact that the feature film reinforces the deterring notion that personal assistants are...[*missing word or idiom*]... to/of/for high-level executives.

Comment: +1 I would phrase it: "*the notion that personal assistants work exclusively for high-level executives*", or "*... are exclusively for high-level executives*". [You need *disgruntled*, not *disgruntling*, by the way ...]

Comment: What about "exclusive"?!

Comment: thank you @Araucaria, very useful and also thank you for pointing out that it should be disgruntled.

Comment: What's a "deterring notion"? Is the issue that this notion deters people from becoming AAs, or that it deters lower-level execs from trying to hire them? (Also, isn't she a personal assistant or executive assistant in TDWP?)

Comment: I've also never seen "disgruntling" as an active verb before.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker and used as an intransitive verb, no less.  It's actually transitive, and *usually* in passive form.  This disgruntles me slightly, but not as much as the deterring notion that "deter" can be used without any direct or indirect object.  :P

Answer (score 9):

The word ***reserved*** (meaning *set aside for specific people* in this context) works here.

> "... the deterring notion that personal assistants are ***reserved*** for high-level executives."

ODO:

> **[reserved](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/reserved)**
>   *adjective*
>
> **2.** kept by special arrangement for some person: a reserved seat.

Answer (score 9):

Alternatively '[prerogative](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/prerogative)' may be what you are looking for

> A right or privilege exclusive to a particular individual or class:
>   *‘in some countries, higher education is predominantly the prerogative
>   of the rich’*

Per your example

> the feature film reinforces the deterring notion that personal
>   assistants are the prerogative of high-level executives.

This can also be intensified by the use of 'sole'

> the feature film reinforces the deterring notion that personal
>   assistants are the sole prerogative of high-level executives.

Comment: This is a particularly nice suggestion and one I didn't think of.

Comment: One note. Although *sole prerogative* is still the dominant form overall, consider "solely the prerogative" here. With "sole prerogative", it sounds like assistants are the only executive prerogative, rather than that all assistants work for execs.

Answer (score 5):

[Peculiar to](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/peculiar) 
 perhaps not the most common usage of 'peculiar' but i think it would work in the example.

> 2.1 **peculiar to** Belonging exclusively to:

- > ‘some languages are peculiar to one region’
- > ‘ I'm not sure if all people do this, or whether it's something
  >   peculiar to my family.’

In your example:

> the feature film reinforces the deterring notion that personal
>   assistants are peculiar to high-level executives."

Though I might rephrase to something like

> the feature film reinforces the deterring notion that having personal
>   assistants is peculiar to high-level executives."

Comment: Why the downvote? The question asked for ' a word (or idiom or phrase) that describes something which is perceived as belonging to one person or group of people only'. Which 'peculiar to' fits. if there is some other aspect to my answer that is incorrect in some way, it will be easier for me to correct if you let me know what it is. Peace.

Comment: I'm not the downvoter but perhaps whoever did downvvote was either unaware of the exact (and correct) use you pointed out, or was on a drive-by downvote which, sadly, does happen. I find your answer to be factually and semantically correct. +1 from me.

Comment: @Spagirl Thank you, I found your answer very helpful and I don't see why someone would downvote it. Also, the way you rephrased it flows a lot smoother so again, thank you for that.

Comment: Cheers for the affirmative comments folks. :)

Comment: You might also consider "proprietary".

Comment: It's the first thing that came to mind, but may not be the best. I think *peculiar to* is mostly not used this way with humans - neither "(human) is peculiar to ..."  nor "... is peculiar to (human)" is very common. (But it can be used to great effect if the people are in fact peculiar, as is done in the second example.)

Comment: Agree that using it to refer to humans directly would be a little 'off', which is why i also suggested a tweak to the OP's example question to make it be about the employment of PAs rather than the PAs themselves.

Answer (score 5):

**[Exclusive](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/exclusive) (to)** works particularly well here:

> **exclusive** *adjective*
>
> (postpositive) *foll by to.* limited (to); found only (in):
>
> > *this model is exclusive to Harrods*

As well as meaning something belongs to a particular place, group or individual, it connotes a degree of privilege and status often associated with the group under discussion.

**[Limited](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/limited) (to)** and **[reserved](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/reserved) (for)** have similar connotations.

---

More generally, **[idiosyncratic](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/idiosyncratic) (to)** and **[peculiar](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/peculiar) (to)** mean exactly what you intend:

> **idiosyncratic** *adjective*
>
> […] something peculiar to an individual
>
> **peculiar** *adjective*
>
> 4. belonging characteristically (usually followed by to):
>
>    > *an expression peculiar to Canadians.*
> 5. belonging exclusively to some person, group, or thing:
>
>    > *the peculiar properties of a drug.*

Answer (score 3):

**sole purview**

As in "personal assistants are the sole purview of high-level executives".

It's a common and somewhat formal/legal idiom that feels best for this situation.

Here's an [example usage](https://www.facebook.com/thelipsticklib/posts/153906517995660) -- "Will print books be the sole purview of the wealthy?"

**purview**

> 2
>   :  the range or limit of authority, competence, responsibility, concern, or intention

"Purview." Merriam-Webster.com. Merriam-Webster, n.d. Web. 11 Jan. 2017.

Comment: One note. Although sole purview is still the dominant form overall, consider "solely the purview" here. With "sole purview", it sounds like assistants are the only thing within an executive's perview, rather than that all assistants work for execs.

Comment: Another excellent and unexpected suggestion.

Comment: can you explain how this pertains? In what way are PAs the range or limit of any of those things? Perhaps it works if you make it something like 'employment of personal assistants is solely within the purview of...'?

Comment: Yes, I think adding something like "employment of" clarifies the statement, but the action is understood as it is with other suggested words.

Comment: Sorry, i didn't make myself clear. I understand 'purview' to be the scope or range of authority: in what way do PAs, or their employment *constitute* 'range/scope' rather than falling *within* it?

Answer (score 0):

**Endemic**

1. native and/or restricted to a particular area or field
2. characteristic of or prevalent in a particular field, area, or environment

As in personal assistance, belong to, and are inherently restricted to Executives.  This also conveys that this is the natural place for PA's, and the area/reason to which originally gave rise to the role.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of possibilities have been mentioned, but the one I don't see so far is:

***Dedicated*** (adjective)—Exclusively allocated to or intended for a particular purpose

from [Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/dedicated)

---

Some possible phrases:

***Geared towards***

***Meant for***

***Customized to***

Answer (score 0):

**Minion** (but also) devotee, without being derogatory, i.e. as minions to top chefs, hairdressers, designers, who would do 'anything', which may seem demeaning or not part of their job description who learn from amongst the best persons in the industry as well as paying their dues.

Minion: a follower or underling **of** a powerful person, especially a servile or unimportant one (a follower or underling of a powerful person, especially a servile or unimportant one).https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=define+minions

Answer (score 0):

**Property** fits your sentence:
"...the deterring notion that personal assistants are **property of** high-level executives."

It simply means (at risk of committing the etymological fallacy, perhaps) "Something belonging to [someone]".

> **property** (n)
> c. 1300, properte, "nature, quality, distinctive character always present in an individual or class," later "possession, land or goods owned, things subject to ownership" (early 14c., but this sense is rare before 17c.), from an Anglo-French modification of Old French proprete, "individuality, peculiarity; property" (12c., Modern French propreté) and directly from Latin proprietatem (nominative proprietas) "ownership, a property, propriety, quality," literally "special character" (a loan-translation of Greek idioma), noun of quality from proprius "one's own, special" (see proper) [--etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/word/property)

It is commonly understood now that one person can never really be property of another, but many legal systems since the beginning of history have recognized the "owning" of another person. For a rather ironic example, as Paul Finkelman points out,

> The American Constitution does not mention slavery until 1865, with the adoption of the Thirteenth Amendment, which abolished the institution. Yet the Constitution, written in 1787, is riddled with provisions tied to slavery which protected it without naming it. [...] A constant theme of this discussion is how the legal system balanced the dual status of slaves as ‘people’ and as ‘property’.  [--Slavery in the United States](https://scholarship.law.duke.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=5386&context=faculty_scholarship)

Answer (score -1):

A little different, but how about **fodder**?

OD:

> [**fodder**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/fodder): a person or thing regarded only as material for a
>   specific use

Your example:

> "... the feature film reinforces the deterring notion that personal
>   assistants are the **fodder** of high-level executives.

Answer (score -3):

Depending on your intention, you may wish to consider the word **shibboleth**.

> noun: shibboleth; plural noun: shibboleths
>
> A custom, principle, or belief distinguishing a particular class or group of people, especially a long-standing one regarded as outmoded or no longer important.

You could use this word in your example (though it may be stretching the use a bit) to imply that having an assistant is an implicit show of power or position.

Comment: Not the (unhelpfully quiet) downvoter, and this is absolutely a valid observation, but I think this would be an odd way to turn that phrase.

Comment: I have never seen shibboleth used in this way and it would appear very strange. The point of the word shibboleth was to identify a certain group of people (they pronounced it differently) and kill them. In the Yugoslavian conflicts assassins waited outside bakeries to hear how people asked for bread for the same reason.